# Continuity in topology, $f(U)\subset f(V) \implies U\subset V$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

[image]Basically the title. I am reading "Introductory Real Analysis", by Kolmogorov & Fomin, and understand equivalence between usual $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity and continuity a point in a topological space, and can't deduce from that why the general continuity in topological spaces follows because I can't understand why does $f(U)\subset f(V) \implies U\subset V$ for continuous mappings $f$ and $U,V$ are open sets.
P.S.
I only deduced this for $f$ being bijective, but can't proceed for general $f$.

Comment: it's not true... for example $\sin((0,2\pi))=\sin((4\pi,6\pi))$, but $(0,2\pi)\not\subset (4\pi, 6\pi)$

Comment: It's true for injective functions, but not more generally.

Comment: Yup, that's what I deduced only, but it is written there, wait let me actually send it (question is now edited).

Comment: @Surb I don't think your counter example works because you'd require that the statement read $f(U)\subseteq f(V)$

Comment: @Chickenmancer Be aware that while some write $\subseteq$ as subset and $\subset$ as proper subset, not all do.  In fact, from the context in the image, it looks like _this_ author writes $\subset$ for the subset relation (typically then $\subsetneq$ is used for the proper subset relation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $\Gamma=f^{-1}(G)$. As $f(U_x)\subset G$ we get $U_x \subset f^{-1}(G)=\Gamma$ by the definition of preimage. Am I missing something? The statement you propose if false but it is not required in the proof.